# Drawing on screen outside notebooks

Tags: graphics, notebooks, display, overlay

Is there a way to display (animated) graphics outside of Mathematica notebooks, i.e., in a specified rectangle on the screen? I can imagine that one way to achieve that is by creating a notebook without borders, menu, or any other elements, and configuring it such that it stays always on top. Can this be achieved?

**Update:** I wonder whether `AttachCell` or other functions offer enough control to create a rectangular canvas (no window border or window elements) that stays always on top, allow control over transparency, and possibly hide the mouse cursor when it is moved over the "window" region. Think of something like a splash screen displaying an image with transparent regions for example. I agree that this is possible with Python/Tkinter for example but I am wondering how much of such detailed control is exposed in Mathematica.

Comment: `CreateDialog[...]` doesn't look like it will give you all the control you need, so I'd imagine you'd have to create a native application or python script that popped open a window at the right position, then you could send `Rasterize`'d graphics to it via function calls, or you could get it to render SVG you created by sending it strings from `ExportString[..., "SVG"]`. In any case it will probably involve a non-mathematica element. It's not really possible to just write raw data to the framebuffer these days.

Comment: Take a look at options I used to create a floating menu before attached cells were known: https://github.com/kubaPod/DevTools/blob/master/DevTools/DevTools.m#L652
Keep in mind that you need to close this notebook at one point so keep a reference to a notebook object somewhere.